# output the verbose message when using flutter pub get

Tags: flutter

I am using flutter to build a projetct, now I am running get command but stuck for more than one hour, is it possible to output a detail message to know the problem. This stuck like this in Android Studio:

```
/Users/dolphin/apps/flutter/bin/flutter --no-color pub get
Running "flutter pub get" in Cruise...
```

when I execute command in Terminal it works fine:

```
~/source/third-party/Cruise on  master! ⌚ 10:55:37
$  ~/apps/flutter/bin/flutter pub get
Running "flutter pub get" in Cruise...                              0.6s
```

this is my android studio proxy settings:

[image]

what should I do to make it works fine in Android studio?

Answer (score 0):

using this command will found all listening on localhost:

```
$ lsof -i:7890
COMMAND     PID    USER   FD   TYPE             DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
Google      535 dolphin   20u  IPv4 0x46a2e89295f84f31      0t0  TCP localhost:54480->localhost:7890 (ESTABLISHED)
Google      535 dolphin   26u  IPv4 0x46a2e89278d11dd1      0t0  TCP localhost:54554->localhost:7890 (ESTABLISHED)
Google      535 dolphin   28u  IPv4 0x46a2e8927887b191      0t0  TCP localhost:54610->localhost:7890 (ESTABLISHED)
Google      535 dolphin   30u  IPv4 0x46a2e89298b92551      0t0  TCP localhost:54558->localhost:7890 (ESTABLISHED)
Google      535 dolphin   32u  IPv4 0x46a2e89298ebe7b1      0t0  TCP localhost:54310->localhost:7890 (CLOSE_WAIT)
Google      535 dolphin   35u  IPv4 0x46a2e892776e7551      0t0  TCP localhost:54316->localhost:7890 (CLOSE_WAIT)
Google      535 dolphin   38u  IPv4 0x46a2e892776e8911      0t0  TCP localhost:54330->localhost:7890 (ESTABLISHED)
Google      535 dolphin   48u  IPv4 0x46a2e89280aa4551      0t0  TCP localhost:54322->localhost:7890 (CLOSE_WAIT)
Google      535 dolphin   54u  IPv4 0x46a2e89278d127b1      0t0  TCP localhost:54323->localhost:7890 (CLOSE_WAIT)
Google      535 dolphin   56u  IPv4 0x46a2e89298febf31      0t0  TCP localhost:54331->localhost:7890 (ESTABLISHED)
```

so tweak the proxy:

[image]